# C code translation into MIPS

Tags: c, assembly, mips

How would I translate the following code into MIPS assembly language?

```
# include < stdio .h >
int fibRecursive ( int n )
{
   int answer ;
   if ( n < 2 ) {
   answer = n ;
   }
   else {
     answer = fibRecursive ( n - 1 ) + fibRecursive ( n - 2 ) ;
   }
   return answer ;
}

int main ( int argc , char * argv [] )
{
   int input = 10;
   int result = fibRecursive ( input ) ;
   printf ( " The %d - th Fibonacci number is % d .\ n " , input , result ) ;
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help.
I am having trouble with the line:

```
answer = fibRecursive ( n - 1 ) + fibRecursive ( n - 2 ) ;
```

Here is the MIPS I have so far:

```
fibRecursive:
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $s0, $zero, 0
slti $t0, $a0, 2
beq $t0, $zero, ELSE
add $s0, $a0, $zero
j EXIT

ELSE:
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $a0, 0($sp)
addi $a0, $a0, -1
jal fibRecursive

EXIT:
add $v0, $zero, $s0
```

Comment: I think a compiler could help you with this task?

Comment: I know I need the actual MIPS code though!

Comment: You can read the compiler's output.

Comment: It's your homework, do it yourself.

Comment: @user1998581 do you know MIPS assembly language?

Comment: gcc or armcc or whatever with the -S flag.  Outputs a nice assembler file for you to look at.  See how the compiler does it and then hand roll your own for work or homework if needed.

Comment: @shf301 I know it very little. What I'm having most trouble with is the recursive call in the code. I am having trouble adding two recursive calls

Comment: @user1998581 if this really is homework, compiler output i'm sure will not be what your professor wants to see. It will most certainly not look like MIPS assembly that you do by hand, as it will include optimizations from the compiler.

Comment: @user1998581 What's the problem. just call the function again? Did you save the registers your function destroys when entering the function and restore it when leaving?

Comment: @Kevin it's actually an optional assignment that I am just having trouble with. It's not my actual homework

Comment: @junix I understand how to call the function once but I am having trouble adding another recursive call to the previously called function that is where I am having trouble I'm not sure how to translate it

Comment: @user1998581 There is no difference in calling a function "recursively" it's a call like every other call. The name of the label is just "by accident" the same as the label of the caller.

Answer (score 2):

I would run a compiler (like GCC) with a flag set to emit assembler code. (e.g. for GCC you can use the [-S](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S-80) option)

Comment: how do I put a flag on the compiler?

Comment: It will generate Intel Assembly, NOT MIPS!

Comment: @user1998581 It's a command line switch placed in the command line when invoking the compiler. e.g. `gcc -S foo.c`

Comment: @Blood Depends on the cross-compiler you invoke isn't it?

Comment: You mentioned gcc and it doesn't support MIPS assembly

Comment: @Blood, if he's asking for MIPs assembler, one would hope he has access to a MIPs compiler...

Comment: mips compiler doesn't support this kind of things

Comment: Umm.  Depends on which one now doesn't it?  I use one that does for my development and I'm sure there are others as well.

Comment: @Blood GCC is able to generate code for MIPS so I am expecting it's also able to emit the Mnemonics of the code. (As there is no difference) But I admint I didn't test it. Of course you can also use objdump if you like. I also wonder what "mips compiler" you are referring to which should not support assembly output?

Comment: @junix Nvm, i misunderstood one thing. Can you tell me how gcc can generate code for MIPS? Because i couldn't find it.

Comment: @Blood: If you're not developing on a MIPS platform, you will most likely need a cross-compiler

Answer (score 1):

```
// Swapped to MIPs syntax :)
main:
  jal function
  ...

function:
  // if code here
  // return value here
  jal function
  // gather answer into reg.
  jal function
  // add away
  // return value here
  ...
```

There, you now see how to have a recursive function be called twice in main.  Cleaning up the end cases is left as an exercise for the user.

Comment: answer = fibRecursive ( n - 1 ) + fibRecursive ( n - 2 ) is the line I am having trouble with not the main function

Comment: Same thing...  If you can call the function twice, gathering the answers into registers, then what's the problem.  Here's I'll change the example slightly...

Comment: Isn't that ARM assembly? Thought for MIPS it's JAL?

Comment: I just don't understand where to put the second recursive call... I know I probably sound like an idiot but I am just learning this. I have added the code I have

Comment: Lol - I'm working with PPC code - my bad.  Not quite the same now is it.  Still, BL, call, jal, pop pc, etc.  Confusing once you know a few.  I'll leave it for now, but yes, it should be Jump And Link for MIPs.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I understand what you are saying now. I think I figured it out, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Compiled to MIPS I get this
    .file   1 "c2mips.c"

```
 # -G value = 8, Cpu = 3000, ISA = 1
 # GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404 (mips-mips-ecoff) compiled by GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404.
 # options passed:  -msoft-float
 # options enabled:  -fpeephole -ffunction-cse -fkeep-static-consts
 # -fpcc-struct-return -fcommon -fverbose-asm -fgnu-linker -msoft-float
 # -meb -mcpu=3000

gcc2_compiled.:
__gnu_compiled_c:
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  fibRecursive
    .ent    fibRecursive
fibRecursive:
    .frame  $fp,40,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 3/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0010000,-8
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,40
    sw  $31,32($sp)
    sw  $fp,28($sp)
    sw  $16,24($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $4,40($fp)
    lw  $2,40($fp)
    slt $3,$2,2
    beq $3,$0,$L2
    lw  $2,40($fp)
    sw  $2,16($fp)
    j   $L3
$L2:
    lw  $3,40($fp)
    addu    $2,$3,-1
    move    $4,$2
    jal fibRecursive
    move    $16,$2
    lw  $3,40($fp)
    addu    $2,$3,-2
    move    $4,$2
    jal fibRecursive
    addu    $3,$16,$2
    sw  $3,16($fp)
$L3:
    lw  $3,16($fp)
    move    $2,$3
    j   $L1
$L1:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,32($sp)
    lw  $fp,28($sp)
    lw  $16,24($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,40
    j   $31
    .end    fibRecursive
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC0:
    .ascii  " The %d - th Fibonacci number is % d . n \000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,32,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,32
    sw  $31,28($sp)
    sw  $fp,24($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $4,32($fp)
    sw  $5,36($fp)
    jal __main
    li  $2,10           # 0x0000000a
    sw  $2,16($fp)
    lw  $4,16($fp)
    jal fibRecursive
    sw  $2,20($fp)
    la  $4,$LC0
    lw  $5,16($fp)
    lw  $6,20($fp)
    jal printf
    move    $2,$0
    j   $L4
$L4:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,28($sp)
    lw  $fp,24($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,32
    j   $31
    .end    main
```

Comment: How did you "compile to MIPS"?

Comment: @bafromca I used the tool [MipsIT](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1200/2006-2007/mips-lab/MipsICT.exe)

Comment: is that your school's website? It says Page Not Found, possibly because I'm not a student there? Any chance you can upload the executable?

Comment: @bafromca Yes. And yes. They shut it down, link rot. We got the file though. My school project was with MIPS. You can get it from me (nik AT kth.se) or try [download it](https://bitbucket.org/niklasr/cyberfaze/downloads/MipsICT.exe) at this new place before the link rots or similar.